# Convert wget to zapier

Tags: wget, zapier

I have tried to find a solution to this without success. We have this app and we successfully can make HTTP posts with wget like these:

```
wget -qO- --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies cookies.txt https://example.com/usuarios/login/26960 | grep "name='__csrf_magic'" | sed 's/.value="(.)".*/\1/' > csrf.txt
wget -qO- --keep-session-cookies --load-cookies cookies.txt --save-cookies cookies.txt --post-data "email=<email>&code=<code>" https://example.com//usuarios/login
wget --keep-session-cookies --load-cookies cookies.txt --post-data "dados" 'https://example.com/pesquisas/insert'
wget -qO- --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies cookies.txt https://example.com/usuarios/logoff
```

How to convert this wget calls to Zapier?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried and the errors you are receiving.

Comment: This is maybe possible via python and the `requests` library. You won't be able to store the cookies in a file, but you'll be able to keep them at runtime and use them in a second (or third/fourth) request.